# Kendo Scheduler Custom time slot creation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

i want to create custom time slot in kendo day scheduler.  For example i want to create the time slot of 15 min duration from 9:00 am to 1:00 pm and after that i want to create time slot of 30 minutes duration from 1:00 pm to 5:00 pm. i am getting time slots from DB and i want to create slots as it is as its coming from DB.how can i Override the default slot creation of kendo calendar.By defining "majorTick" i am getting all slots with same time duration but i want to customize this duration according to the time coming from DB with each row. Any suggestion/idea to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Scheduler doesn't support this behavior at all.

If you'll make changes to the table element itself you'll probably break the scheduler's functionality.

**A possible solution is this:**

1. Set the major/minor tick size (according to your preference) to the smallest common denominator among all the slot sizes you got from the server.
2. Override all the `move, moveEnd, resize, resizeEnd...` events to cancel any changes if the change made didn't fit the "actual slot size" in that time.

Use `e.preventDeafault();` to cancel the changes.

If you need further explanation, let me know.

Comment: How can i customize the time of a slot .by defining major tick size to the smallest common denominator it creates all slot with same time duration but i want to create slots duration which is coming from server side.could you please give me any suggestion/example.